# m2eclipse .classpath generation with AJDT

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, ajdt

I am using m2eclipse 0.10.2 and eclipse helios/ajdt. 
I remember that m2eclipse is managing the inpath for eclipse configuration (at least in eclipse galileo)

right now, it doesn't manage it for me any more and I don't know why. This is my plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I can add my aspectLibrary to the inpath manually and eclipse adds it to the .classpath file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.ajdt.inpath.restriction" value="spring-aspects-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.ajdt.inpath" value="org.eclipse.ajdt.inpath"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ASPECTJRT_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

When i configure my project (right-click > maven) and select "Update Project Configuration", it looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ASPECTJRT_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
 </classpath>
```

so my inpath is gone and i don't see any aspect markers anymore.

Does anybody can give me some advice?
Is it working on your site?
Can you send me the steps and pom config to let m2eclipse mange my ajdt inpath?

BTW: I am having a multi-module.

regards J

Comment: I'm having the same problems with m2eclipse. Too bad there is no answer to this one...

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this as well, but couldn't find any Jira issue assigned to the project.  Do you intend to open one?

Comment: I have switched to maven eclipse plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) . I was trying to use m2eclipse for two years and i always had problems. Like you can debug into your jar source code. You have to add manually every single jar. some other things are suddenly not working. Soemtimes i have to rebuild/clean over and over again. And suddenly my compile errors went away, i didn't know why. With the regular maven plugin you dont have such problems, you always know what the plugin is doing.